# word2vec application to non-human words: implementation allowing to provide my own context and distance

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

I would like to use *word2vec* to transform 'words' into numerical vectors and possibly make predictions for new words. I've tried extracting features from words manually and training a linear regression model (using Stocahstic Gradient Descent), but this only works to an extent.

**The input data I have is:**

- Each word is associated with a numerical value. You can think of this value as being the word's coordinate in 1D space.
- For each word I can provide a distance to any other word (because I have the words' coordinates).

  - because of this I can provide the context for each word. If given a distance, I can provide all the other words within this distance from the target one.
- Words are composed from latin letters only (e.g. AABCCCDE, BKEDRRS).
- Words almost never repeat, but their structural elements repeat a lot within different words.
- Words can be of different length (say 5-50 letters max).
- Words have common features, some subsequences in them will occur multiple times in different words (e.g. some dublets or triplets of letters, their position within a word, etc).

**The question**:

Is there an implementation of *word2vec* which allows provision of your own distances and context for each word?

A big bonus would be if the trained model could spit out the predicted coordinate for any word you feed in after training.

Preferrably in Java, Python is also fine, but in general anything will do.

I am also not restricting myself to *word2vec*, it just seems as a good fit, but my knowledge of machine-learning and data mining are very limited, so I might be missing a better way to tackle the problem.

PS: I know about `deeplearning4j`, but I haven't looked around the code enough to figure out if what I want to do is easy to implement in it.

**Example of data:** (typical input contains thousands to tens of thousands of words)

`ABCD      0.50
ABCDD     0.51
ABAB      0.30
BCDAB     0.60
DABBC     0.59
SPQTYRQ   0.80`

Comment: It is not clear the 1D coordinate is really 1D. I have a feeling it is a subjective projection of more features, which you are trying to recover by embedding. You have also mentioned larger words composing of smaller words as patterns. Does that affects distance between them? How do the coordinates come about?

Comment: @Mai the 'words' are representations of chemical compounds (peptides or proteins), the 1D coordinates are some property of those compounds being measured by an instrument. It is really 1D, just a single scalar value. The distance definitely is affected by the words' length and composition.

Comment: I am pretty certain a straight implementation of word2vec is not the solution here. In word2vec, the words are just labels for a point in hyperspace – the structure of the label has no bearing on its position. I am assuming your labels DO have a bearing on the word's location. Therefore, in effect, you are attempting to add dimensions to your one-dimensional model, by decomposing labels, to gain further insight and make predictions about the existence of new labels? If so, could you view each label as a sentence (thus context) and use each letter as a word?

Comment: @JohnWakefield Thanks John! It is true that the labels do have a bearing on the words' location. And the goal is not to predict new labels, but rather given a new, yet unseen, label make a prediction about it's location. If I do it like you suggest with letters treated as words and whole labels as sentences, then how would I use my location data that is attached to each label? There will need to be some inter-sentence dependencies then?